# Console (Input string was not in correct format)

Tags: c#

Hi guys so i'm starting to learn C# and I came up with this problem when I  was trying to mix things up

It says "Input string was not in correct format" at the
n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Here's the whole code

```
namespace Exercise13
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char choice;
            Console.Write("What operation would you like to use?");
            Console.WriteLine("\na. Addition \tb. Subtraction \tc.Multiplication \td.Division");
            choice = (char)Console.Read();
            if (choice == 'a')
            {
                sumValues();
            }
            else if (choice == 'b') 
            {
                minusValues();
            }
            else if (choice == 'c') 
            {
                timesValues();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        static void sumValues() 
        {


            int n = 0;
            int sum = 0;
            int i = 0,val = 0;
            Console.Write("How many numbers do you want calculate: ");
            n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());            

            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
            {
                Console.Write("\nInput number: ");
                val = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                sum += val;

            }
            Console.Write("\nThe Answer is: "+sum);

        }
        static void minusValues() 
        {
            int diff = 0, m, z, value;
            Console.Write("How many numbers do you want calculate: ");
            m = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            for (z = 0; z < m; z++)
            {
                Console.Write("\nInput number: ");
                value = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                diff -= value;

            }
            Console.Write("\nThe Answer is: " + diff);

        }
        static void timesValues()
        {
            int prod = 0, e, i, val;
            Console.Write("How many numbers do you want to calculate: ");
            e = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            for (i = 0; i < e; i++) 
            {
                Console.Write("\nInput number: ");
                val = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                prod *= val;
            }
            Console.Write("\nThe answer is: " + prod);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The exception is (as are most) reasonably clear: the string you passed to the `Convert` class was not in a valid format for the type you want returned (`int` in this case). Enter a valid integer as a string, and it will work.

Comment: I was typing 1.I tried all of your Answers all of them worked well in their own right. I Saved 3 files based on 3 of your answers for future references :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Integer.TryParse to handle the strings potentially not being numbers. Then prompt the user if the input is not parsable to enter valid input.

Convert and Parse both will throw exceptions if the string is not an exact number.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
        int n = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int i = 0,val = 0;
        Console.Write("How many numbers do you want calculate: ");
        var isValidNumber = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n);
        if(!isValidNumber) {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid number entered!");
        }
        else {
           //Use the number
        }
```

Comment: The idea is correct but the code is wrong. A little attention to details such as method signatures and c# syntax would make it a good answer.

Comment: It does compile now, and next time suggest efforts edits if you know what is wrong next time. It was written on a mobile phone, so I was showing psuedocode. Sorry the syntax was slightly off

Comment: Well, I've upvoted to balance off the -1 score since it now does actually compile :-)

Comment: Removed the downvote, but @ZoharPeled +10 against a -2 is not a very balanced action. If we only have a way to inform the other downvoters would be preferable.

Comment: @Steve I agree it's not really balancing the reputation points but it does balance the post score. I won't retract my upvote since a. It's currently a valid solution and b. I'll have to edit it again to retract. all things considered I think it's fair.