# Input string was not in a correct format. Not sure how to convert input string c#

Tags: c#

I have a tic tac toe solution. My code runs upto the point where both users can input their names and the board is generated on the console app. But when the player goes to make a selection which is a character (X or O) i get 'System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

I understand i need to use TryParse but not sure how to use it in this example

```
do
{
    board.GameBoard();
    Console.WriteLine("\n");
    if (chance == 0)
    {
        Console.Write(playerOne.Name + " turn, make your selection: ");
    }
    else if (chance % 2 == 1)
    {
        Console.Write(playerTwo.Name + " turn, make your selection: ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\n");

    // Code fails on the line below
    int choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

> System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Comment: Are you trying to convert an `X` or `O` to an `int`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Console (Input string was not in correct format)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313017/console-input-string-was-not-in-correct-format)

Comment: I don't get it, 'X' and 'O' are not integers, what do you expect from an int conversion?

Comment: As the user can only choose X or O which is a string but on the board it's just numbers. 

PlayerOne a is X
PlayerTwo s is O
     |     |
  1  |  2  |  3
_____|_____|_____
     |     |
  4  |  5  |  6
_____|_____|_____
     |     |
  7  |  8  |  9
     |     |
  


a turn, make your selection:

x

Comment: Could you show us the result of the `Console.ReadLine()`? (in general I think I would first put it in a variable and then feed that variable to the `Convert.ToInt32`)

Answer (score 1):

Might this work?:

```
string choice = Console.ReadLine();
int choiceValue; 

  bool success = Int32.TryParse(choice , out choiceValue);

  if(success){
    // it was a number then do an operation
  }
  else{
   // was not a number do other operation
}
```

Can read upon tryparse [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8)